# What's the LINQ to select the latest item from a number of versioned items?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I've got a class like the following:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceId {get;set;}
    public int VersionId {get;set;}
}
```

Each time an `Invoice` is modified, the `VersionId` gets incremented, but the `InvoiceId` remains the same. So given an `IEnumerable<Invoice>` which has the following results:

```
InvoiceId VersionId
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         1
2         2
```

How can I get just the results:

```
InvoiceId VersionId
1         3
2         2
```

I.e. I want just the Invoices from the results which have the latest VersionId. I can easily do this in T-SQL, but cannot for the life of me work out the correct LINQ syntax. I'm using Entity Framework 4 Code First.

Comment: If you have to do this all the time, it might be best to have a materialized or indexed view which you can select from instead. Might be faster and save headaches down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by the `VersionId`, group them by `InvoiceId`, then take the first result of each group. Try this:

```
var query = list.OrderByDescending(i => i.VersionId)
                .GroupBy(i => i.InvoiceId)
                .Select(g => g.First());
```

EDIT: how about this approach using `Max`?

```
var query = list.GroupBy(i => i.InvoiceId)
                .Select(g => g.Single(i => i.VersionId == g.Max(o => o.VersionId)));
```

Try using `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` in place of `Single` as well... it would give the same result although `Single` shows the intention better.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea I'm not familiar with EF much. Can you try my second approach?

Comment: @Ahmad - I think it may have worked, but I'd worked out the incorrect number of expected results. I'm off home now, so I'll try again in the morning.

Comment: @Ahmad: I'm no T-SQL expert. Is the query you've written likely to have the same performance as my second one? In Linq to Objects, I know it wouldn't (quadratic), but I'm not sure if that applies here.

Comment: @Ani that makes two of us :) I don't think the difference would be that drastic depending on the size of the data but the `let` keyword will definitely generate an intermediate statement that the SQL will use, similar to `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT generated by let here) ...`. Mine might be a little better in that sense. For LINQ to Objects it's probably not worth worrying about too much up front.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I've tested both these queries with LINQ to Entities. They seem to work, so perhaps the issue is something else?

---

Option 1:

```
var latestInvoices = invoices.GroupBy(i => i.InvoiceId)
                             .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(i => i.VersionId)
                                                   .FirstOrDefault());
```

EDIT: Changed 'Last' to 'FirstOrDefault', LINQ to Entities has issues with the 'Last' query operator.

---

Option 2:

```
var invoices = from invoice in dc.Invoices
               group invoice by invoice.InvoiceId into invoiceGroup
               let maxVersion = invoiceGroup.Max(i => i.VersionId)
               from candidate in invoiceGroup
               where candidate.VersionId == maxVersion
               select candidate;
```

Comment: Looks OK, just testing it now in my actual app.

Comment: I get the error "Unable to create a constant value of type 'XYZ'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context." when using EntityFramework.

Comment: Oh sorry, I only tested with LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Ok, I tried with LINQ to Entities. Both these queries seem to work (changed the first one to `FirstOrDefault`). I'm quite confused now.. :)

Comment: The second one worked fine, however it wasn't as readable as Ahmad's answer. But +1 though, thanks Ani!

Answer (score 1):

My version:

```
var h = from i in Invoices
        group i.VersionId by i.InvoiceId into grouping
        select new {InvoiceId = grouping.Key, VersionId = grouping.Max()};
```

**Update**

As was mentioned by Ahmad in the comments, the above query will return a projection. The version below will return a `IQueryable<Invoice>`. I use composition to build the query because I think it is more clear.

```
var maxVersions = from i in Invoices
                  group i.VersionId by i.InvoiceId into grouping
                  select new {InvoiceId = grouping.Key, 
                              VersionId = grouping.Max()};

var latestInvoices =  from i in Invoices
                      join m in maxVersions 
                      on new {i.InvoiceId, i.VersionId} equals 
                         new {m.InvoiceId, m.VersionId}
                      select i;
```

Comment: This projects into an anonymous type rather than using the existing `Invoice` objects. Ani and I show how to use `Max` and maintain the original objects in both query and fluent syntaxes.

Comment: @Ahmad Mageed: True, but it may still fulfill the OP's requirements. I added another version that will return an `EntitySet`.